# Can I pass a function to another function the call that function with dependencies?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

The title probably doesn't make sense, but basically I;t like to take an object like this...

```
[
    {
        menuItemTitle: 'Edit Page',
        checkPermissions: function($http, $timeout){

            // Do something which uses $http or $timeout

        }
    }
]
```

I have a menu directive which needs to loop through the array and for each item it needs to check whether .checkPermissions is a function and if it is a function then it needs to call it and somehow get all the dependencies passed in and allow them to be used inside the function, just like Angular does when you create a controller, factory, service etc.

I guess the function also needs to run in the context in which it was called so that other variables in the original context would also be available on the "this" object, e.g.

```
var siteId = 'google.com'

var menu = [
    {
        menuItemTitle: 'Edit Page',
        checkPermissions: function($http, $timeout){

            if(siteId === 'google.com'){
                $http.get(stuff);
            }

        }
    }
]
```

I can find loads of articles about how to use DI in controllers and services but none about using the injector system yourself to run passed functions like this, so I presume it's really hard? My JS skills don't stretch to understanding the core Angular code so any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: In the end it does look like you're are trying to solve a routing-problem? Is that right? In this case, show a certain menuitem if the user has a certain role?

Comment: Yes, Indeed, but I may need to do this in other places too. In this instances I have to have the function in a settings object and pass it to another function to be run later, much like the UI-router does and the UI-bootstrap Modal service does with it's "resolve" functionality, both allow you to pass a function in and they resolve your dependencies for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should use the same way as being used in Angular and third-party libraries for DI-enabled functions, [`$injector.invoke`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector#invoke).

It basically calls `checkPermissions` (which should be a function or inline array annotation) with respective dependencies as params, an optional argument can be also provided as `this` context for a function.

```
var checkPermissionsResult = $injector.invoke(checkPermissions, this);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of .invoke(), that looks like what I need. Just one thing I don't understand - this is the current context, the context where the function is being invoked, but if i wanted to use the context in which the function is specified, how would I pass that in? I can't pass it in as a parameter because the parameters all need to be services which are being injected, don't they? I can't do passThis: function($timeout, $http, this){}. Maybe I need to pass both the function and the context as an object.

Comment: It is more idiomatic to use `this` as the context of execution, doing opposite often results in pain. `invoke` accepts local dependencies, this is how it is usually treated in Angular. You can save the desired context as `menu` array prop and pass it to function as `$injector.invoke(checkPermissions, null, { context: desiredContext })`, `checkPermissions` function can now accept local `context` dependency.

Comment: Any way, you can use `self` trick anywhere in JS, `var self = this; var menu = [{ checkPermissions: function($http, $timeout) { self ... }]`.

Comment: Ah that's true, I don've even need to pass self in because wherever the function is declared it will have access to variables in outer functions because of the way JS scopes work, I think :) I'll have a play and try it all out. Thanks.